# Unable to install glide in Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, glide-golang

Trying to install glide via command  `glide install` but unable to

> glide install No command 'glide' found, did you mean:

glide -h
No command 'glide' found, did you mean:
Command 'glade' from package 'glade' (universe)
glide: command not found

Answer (score 1):

On 16.x, you must add the ppa first. Have you done it yet ?

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:masterminds/glide && sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install glide
```

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu Precise (12.04), Trusty (14.04), Wily (15.10) or Xenial (16.04) you nedd to install it using the PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:masterminds/glide && sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install glide
```